# YAML key consisting of a list of elements

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I need to have a list of elements as a key, so that I can check if several conditions are met. 
Example (don't know if this is possible and if the syntax is correct):

```
mapping:
  c_id:
    [pak, gb]: '4711'
    [pak, ch]: '4712'
    [pak]: '4713'
  d_id:
    .
    .
    .
```

Now I need to know if it is possible to have an approach as in the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to Anthon's answer, here is how you can do it with PyYaml:

```
mapping:
  c_id:
    !!python/tuple [pak, gb]: '4711'
    !!python/tuple [pak, ch]: '4712'
    !!python/tuple [pak]: '4713'
```

The trick is to tell PyYaml that you want to load the keys into a tuple (since a list cannot be used as dict key). There is no way to do this *implicitly*, but this does not mean that it is not possible.

Explicit keys may be more readable in this case:

```
mapping:
  c_id:
    ? !!python/tuple [pak, gb]
    : '4711'
    ? !!python/tuple [pak, ch]
    : '4712'
    ? !!python/tuple [pak]
    : '4713'
```

This example is semantically equivalent to the first one.

Comment: Saved my problem, without having to change from PyYAML to any other module, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The syntax for your YAML is correct. The only trick is that because in Python a key has to be immutable you need to specify access to the complex key as a tuple:

```
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
mapping:
  c_id:
    [pak, gb]: '4711'
    [pak, ch]: '4712'
    [pak]: '4713'
"""

data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str)
print(data['mapping']['c_id'][('pak', 'gb')])
```

gives:

```
4711
```

Please note that this is not possible with PyYAML, as it doesn't support sequences as keys, you have to use [`ruamel.yaml`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml/) (disclaimer: I am the author of that package)